# Patent for NPoS (Nominated Proof of Stake)

Tags: npos

Does anyone know where this patent is discussed in the Polkadot or
Substrate docs?

Does anyone know the patent details, numbers, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Working on these... So far:

> Does anyone know where this patent is discussed in the Polkadot docs?

- Empty search for `patent` on https://wiki.polkadot.network/
- Empty search for `patent` on https://spec.polkadot.network/
- 1 result search for `patent` on https://docs.substrate.io

  - Related to Schnorr algorithm: https://docs.substrate.io/deploy/keys-and-network-operations/
- https://www.polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-1-enhanced-economic-security-via-npos

> Does anyone know the patent details, numbers, etc.?

- https://patents.google.com/patent/US20190058581A1/en